# btrfs merge data from two subvolumes and send with clone option

Tags: linux, debian, btrfs

I'm explaining shortly. I have two separate subvolumes for movies and music, that I'm backing up on another disk with send/receive. I would like to merge the two subvolumes in one (with `cp --reflink`) and send this to the backup drive cloning reflinked files from existing snapshots.

I've tried to create `new_volume`, then `cp -rx --reflink "music" "movies"` into it, then:

```
btrfs send \
    -c music-snapshot \
    -c movies-snapshot \
    new_volume-snapshot | btrfs receive /path/to/backup
```

but it complains that can't determine parent for `new_volume` (identified by id):

```
ERROR: parent determination failed for <id_number>
```

Of course `music-snapshot` and `movies-snapshot` exist on backup. I've also tried to snapshot `movies` to `new_volume`, then `cp -rx --reflink "music"` into it, then snapshot and send it with `btrfs send -c music-snapshot -p movies-snapshot new_volume-snapshot`, but it seems that `-c music-snapshot` has no effects, data is sent anyway.

Is what I want to do even possible?

EDIT: I also tried to do this:

```
btrfs sub snap -r movies movies-A
btrfs sub snap -r music music-A 
btrfs sub snap movies new_volume
btrfs sub snap -r new_volume new_volume-A
```

At this point I have:

```
movies-A
music-A
new_volume-A (exact clone of movies-A)
```

Then:

```
cp -rx --reflink music/* new_volume/
btrfs sub snap -r new_volume new_volume-B
```

In the end, with both `movies-A` and `music-A` existing in destination, I can do:

```
btrfs send \
    -p movies-A \
    new_volume-A | btrfs receive /backup/
```

and this is always perfectly working (near to zero data sent). But...

```
btrfs send \
    -p new_volume-A \
    -c music-A \
    new_volume-B | btrfs receive /backup/
```

I don't know how to explain: with "some files" from `music` it works, while with others, it keeps sending data as it was ignoring the source. I think that this way SHOULD definitely work, but I can't reproduce reliably neither the "work" nor the "don't work" behavior. I'm oriented to think that there's a bug somewhere. Could somebody try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(DISCLAIMER: lgaudino's comment suggests that the proposed approach for merging no longer works for btrfs-progs >= [v5.14.2](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/CHANGES.html#btrfs-progs-5-14-2-2021-10-08) due to changed [btrfs-property](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-property.html) behavior when changing the read only status of a snapshot)

What you want can be accomplished, but not directly, because `btrfs send` (and `btrfs receive`) are fairly simple tools, **there is no way to "merge" snapshots into one by providing a secondary parent** from inside the tools.

## On the Sending Side (`btrfs send`)

`btrfs send` outputs *file system* level operations (directory/file creation, transfer of metadata, transfer of file contents, etc.) which can be used by `btrfs receive` on the "receiving side" to create an equivalent snapshot on another btrfs filesystem.  These operations can be seen by performing a "dry run" via [`btrfs receive --dump`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-receive.html).

An **incremental** send (e.g. `btrfs send -p <parent> <snapshot>`) works exactly the same as far as `btrfs send` is concerned, except that only the file system operations necessary for creating `<snapshot>` via modifying (adding/removing directories/files, updating metadata) the `<parent>` are recorded.

There is also no special "parent-child" relationship checking going on.  Assuming the `-p` parameter is used to specify the "parent", `btrfs send` simply generates the necessary commands to get from that snapshot to another (acting as "child").  This would even work if the two snapshots were completely unrelated.

On the sending side, the only requirement `btrfs send` makes is that all snapshots are **read only**.  Read only subvolumes/snapshots are usually generated via the `-r` option in [`btrfs subvolume snapshot -r <subvol> <snap>`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-subvolume.html), although [`btrfs property set <snap> ro true/false`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-property.html) can also be used to change the flag after creation.

`btrfs send` has zero consideration for what is or is not on the receiving side, which is unavoidable since there is no two way communication between the sides like in `rsync` as btrfs send/receive may not even be running at the same time and instead each run at different times reading from/writing to a file.

### There can only be one parent

The [man page](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-send.html) and (old) [wiki FAQ](https://archive.kernel.org/oldwiki/btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ.html#What_is_the_difference_between_-c_and_-p_in_send.3F) are unfortunately rather confusing.  The author of `btrfs-clone` [asserts](https://github.com/mwilck/btrfs-clone#technical-note-btrfs-sends--c-and--p-option) that btrfs send and receive can only at most consider **one** parent for incremental transfers.  The parent can either be directly specified via `-p` or indirectly via one or multiple `-c` options:

> `btrfs-send` from btrfs-tools 4.13 selects the parent for a subvolume
> S and set of given clone sources C_i [like this](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/kdave/btrfs-progs.git/tree/cmds-send.c):
>
> 1. if `-p` option is specified, use it
> 2. if S has no `parent_uuid` set, or this uuid can't be found, give up
> 3. if there's `C_i` with `C_i->uuid == S->parent_uuid` (the subvolume of
>    which S is a child (snapshot), let's call it "mom"), use it
> 4. if no C_i has the same `parent_uuid` as S, give up
> 5. from all C_i that are children of "mom", choose the one that has the
>    closest generation (actually, `ctransid`, what exactly is the difference
>    to "generation"?) to "mom".
>
> Note that [the wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_-c_and_-p_in_send.3F) is a bit misleading, because it suggests that
> `-c` without `p` is different from `-c` with `-p`, although `-p` is
> usually implied by the algorithm above. The only relevant exception is
> sending subvolumes that have no parent.

In summary, I suggest to always explicitly specify one parent via `-p` and to ignore `-c`, `btrfs receive` simply has no such concept as "two parents".

## On the Receiving Side (`btrfs receive`)

The [`btrfs-receive`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-receive.html) man page describes the purpose of the program as:

> Receive a stream of changes and replicate one or more subvolumes that were previously generated by btrfs send

In the case of a full transfer, a new subvolume is created, in the case of an incremental transfer, a new snapshot of the (receiving side equivalent) of `<parent>` snapshot is created.  In either case, the newly created subvolume/snapshot is initially **read write**able until after the "stream of changes" emanating from `btrfs send` has been successfully applied, then the subvolume/snapshot is made **read only**.

Obviously there is no way to implement two parents, since there are no copy-on-write/reflink copies in the "stream of changes" to begin with.  The snapshot of `<parent>` simply provides the base on which the "stream of changes" is applied on.

But how does the receiving side ensure its `<parent>` snapshot is identical with the `<parent>` snapshot on the sending side?  It **never checks/compares the actual contents** of the snapshots/subvolumes, but rather uses *UUID* metadata in connection with the *immutability* assumption for the parent snapshot.

[`btrfs subvolume show <subvolume>`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-subvolume.html) provides output like:

```
/mnt/btrfs/subvolume
        Name:                   subvolume
        UUID:                   5e076a14-4e42-254d-ac8e-55bebea982d1
        Parent UUID:            -
        Received UUID:          -
        Creation time:          2018-01-01 12:34:56 +0000
        Subvolume ID:           79
        Generation:             2844
        Gen at creation:        2844
        Parent ID:              5
        Top level ID:           5
        Flags:                  -
        Snapshot(s):
```

Every subvolume/snapshot has three UUID slots, of which two may be empty.  Every snapshot created by `btrfs subvolume snapshot` always has a `Parent UUID` that clearly identifies its parent and every snapshot created by `btrfs receive` always has a `Received UUID` entry.  If it was a full transfer, it will not have any `Parent UUID` entry, if it was an incremental transfer, it will have both a `Received UUID` entry and a `Parent UUID` entry.  UUID entries cannot be manually changed by the user.

These IDs are sufficient for `btrfs receive` to establish if it possess a "receiving side" `<parent>` snapshot that *should* be completely identical to the "sending side" `<parent>` snapshot, because its `Received UUID` should be equivalent to the sending side parent's UUID, thereby ensuring it was created from it, and the read only status of all snapshots involved means there *should not* have been any changes in the meantime.

(Side Note: While only one side of the two parent volumes contains the Received UUID entry, btrfs send/receive seem to be smart enough to provide this metadata in the "stream of changes", so both sides/file systems can potentially act as the "sending" or "receiving" side, based on user needs)

## How to merge two subvolumes/snapshots (< v5.14.2)

As we have seen, merging is impossible with only `btrfs send/receive` but it is fairly easy to do manually, assuming one wants to combine `movies` and `music` under a new subvolume `unified` and assuming `movies` and `music` are completely mirrored on the receiving side as well:

1. Create a new (empty) subvolume on the sending side: `btrfs subvolume create unified`
2. Change it to read only: `btrfs property set unified ro true`
3. Send it to backup: `btrfs send /path/to/unified | btrfs receive /receiving/side/`
4. Disable read only **on both sides**, e.g. `btrfs property set /path/to/unified ro false` for the sending side
5. Manually `--reflink` the contents of `music` and `movies` to `unified` **on both sides**  `cp -a --reflink /path/to/music /path/to/movies /path/to/unified/`
6. Set **both side**'s `unified` snapshots back to read only `btrfs property set /path/to/unified ro true`
7. Create a new read write snapshot of `unified` to interact with, `unified` will act as the parent for future incremental transfers on **both sides**.

Instead of creating a new/empty subvolume and sending it, one could also just have started at step 4 from a pre-existing `music` or `movies` snapshot.  From the viewpoint of btrfs, the only thing that matters is that the two side's (future) parents are connected via one side's `Received UUID` pointing to the other and both being read only at the time of future transfers.

## What to do for >= v5.14.2

The [least bad solution](http://marc.merlins.org/perso/btrfs/post_2018-03-09_Btrfs-Tips_-Rescuing-A-Btrfs-Send-Receive-Relationship.html) likely is to follow the approach in the previous section but additionally manually reset the `Received UUID` value via [`python-btrfs`](https://github.com/knorrie/python-btrfs) after it was unset by `btrfs-properties`.

There is no *good* solution using just the standard `btrfs-progs` tools.  The closest thing to "a" solution may be to exploit the [fact](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-receive.html#bugs) that the snapshot created during `btrfs receive` is read writeable until the transfer is finished and trying to do our `--reflink` copies before the snapshot gets set to read only by `btrfs-receive`.  In other words, exploiting a **race condition** is currently the only way to do this with only btrfs-progs >=5.14.2 standard tools.

Obviously, what really is needed however is for somebody to make a feature request with the btrfs project to at least allow merging like it was possible before 5.14.2 for people who know what they are doing.

Anyway, an exploit of the race condition would likely look something like this: Since we still can change the read only status of a snapshot on the sending side, we could alter said snapshot, e.g.

use `movies` and reflink copy `music` into it:

```
btrfs property set -f movies ro false
cp -a --reflink /path/to/music /path/to/movies/
btrfs property set -f /path/to/movies ro true   
btrfs subvolume snapshot /path/to/movies /path/to/unified_prep
```

If necessary, we can now move around directories and files within `unified_prep` (but leave the music directory alone), then when ready:

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot -r /path/to/unified_prep /path/to/unified
btrfs send -p /path/to/movies /path/to/unified | btrfs receive /path/to/backups/
```

`btrfs send` and `btrfs receive` should *not* pick up on the additional music directory because it is present in both `movies` (on the sending side) and `unified` (also client side).  Now, IFF we manage to `cp -a --reflink /bkp/to/music /bkp/to/unified/` on the receiving side(!) while the new `unified` snapshot is still being transferred and thus read writeable, then both the sending side `unified` subvolume and its receive side snapshot should be identical and we have successfully merged the subvolumes.

Comment: Hi, @t-nierath thanks for your reply. I already gave you a +1 for the great effort in the explanation. I will definitely try your method asap and mark your answer as accepted if it works for me. It came in just in time, because I thought to merge two subvolumes just in past few days.

Comment: Great, hope it works (it should...). I usually write answers for stuff I want to know myself and didn't find any great answers for online. :)

Comment: It definitely work over SSH! Thank you, you just saved me to transfer over 170GB of data over a slow internet connection :)

The only thing is, I tried to do the same thing on a different drive connected to the same machine, but it spit an error about received_uuid and can't flip ro->rw. If I use the -f (force) flag, the uuid of the subvolume changes and the trick doesn't work anymore, of course. I will do more tries later.

Anyway, Merry Christmas and Happy New Year, kind stranger!!! :)

Comment: damn... looks like they introduced this here, https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/CHANGES.html#btrfs-progs-5-14-2-2021-10-08 my btrfs-progs version is older than that (btrfs-progs v5.10.1)  I currently don't have a system with newer tools, so I can't really test if it's possible to keep the Received_UUID in place, which certainly is necessary for the solution to work

Comment: Now that explains why I can't do the trick on the backup disk on the same machine: this is a new machine with debian 12 and btrfs-progs is version 6.2, while the other two machines which I backup to via ssh are still debian 11, with btrfs-progs 5.10.1. This is a bummer, with the new version this trick will not work anymore.

Comment: Indeed... I added a section, didn't try it and it's ugly as hell... really, I get what the btrfs authors were going for, but they should at least provide an override for powerusers... in any case, Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year to you too!

Comment: Another potential alternative would be to hunt for tools that can manually set the UUID values, like mentioned in this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681639/is-there-any-native-tools-to-modify-uuid-and-received-uuid-of-a-btrfs-subvolume

Comment: Following the link in that question, I found this: http://marc.merlins.org/perso/btrfs/post_2018-03-09_Btrfs-Tips_-Rescuing-A-Btrfs-Send-Receive-Relationship.html It's brutal, you have to manually set the Received_UUID using python-btrfs after you reflinked the files at destination, but I tested it and it works. Hopely I won't need this again anytime soon. It's nice to know that I can do it if I need it, but it would be much better if btrfs developers took the issue and develop an official solution to this problem. I would do it myself, but the matter is far higher than my coding skills.