# Is there any native tools to modify UUID and Received UUID of a BTRFS subvolume?

Tags: btrfs

I have a similar issue described [here](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg75313.html). Basically I need to change the `Received UUID` of a snapshot to fix the parent/child relationship with the `SOURCE` in order to continue using `btrfs send` with `-p SOURCE` option.

[set_received_uuid.py](https://github.com/knorrie/python-btrfs/blob/master/examples/set_received_uuid.py) is mentioned in the mailing thread to set `Received UUID`. However, I'm looking for a native solution if possible. Is there any native btrfs tool that can change `UUID` and `Received UUID` fields of a snapshot?